# Hibernate set default value on select if null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How can I set the default value of

```
select sum(i.price), i.category from item as i where i.customer=:customer group by i.category.
```

So if the customers create their categories and purchase some items in the categories, my query will run fine. However, if the customers just create their categories and not purchase any items, it doesn't return that data. How can I return the category and display 0 instead?

I have tried to get it in the getter but it doesn't work as well:

```
@Column(name="price", columnDefinition="BigDecimal default 0")
public BigDecimal getPrice;
private BigDecimal price;
```

Comment: why dont you just set default value by doing  `private BigDecimal price=0;` so that the query will not return null .Same with `category="notset"`

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

`@Column(name="price")
private BigDecimal getPrice = 0`;

Hope this might help.